# Linear Functional and Direct Sums

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $V$ an vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $0 \neq f \in V$*. Show that there  is $0 \neq v_0 \in V$ such that $ V = Kerf \oplus <v_0>$.

My attempt:

I know that $f \neq 0$ then there is nonzero $v_0$ such that $f(v_0) \neq 0.$

Furthermore $Kerf$ is a Hyperplane, so  $\hspace{0.1cm} Kerf \subset S \subset V \Rightarrow  Kerf = S  \hspace{0.2cm} or \hspace{0.2cm}S= V.$

Hence sums of subspaces is subspaces then  $Kerf + <v_0>$ is a subspace of $\hspace{0.1cm}V$ and $Kerf \subset Kerf + <v_0>$ so we have that $Kerf + <v_0>= V$.

Obviously, $Kerf \hspace{0.1cm}\cap <v_0> = $ {$0$}

This proof it's ok?? if yes there is another way to solve it? if not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine but I sugest proving this without using the hyperplane/codimension idea. Just write any $v$ as $(v-av_0)+ av_0$ where $a =\frac {f(v)} {f(v_0)}$. Note that $v-av_0$ is in the kernel of $f$.